# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #267

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

In some phones the following error is occurring. I am not able to identify the problem by reviewing the log details. log details and xml file contents can view below.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ayush.prana/com.ayush.prana.HomeNew}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #267: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1357)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.Interrogator.a(Interrogator.java:19)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:166)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:158)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:138)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.a(Tap.java:6)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:20)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:9)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.a(ViewInteraction.java:79)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.a(ViewInteraction.java:96)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:3)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5459)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #267: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
    at com.ayush.prana.HomeNew.onCreate(HomeNew.java:75)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6259)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
    at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:184)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2382)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #267: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:971)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:971)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831)
```

The issue is random not facing in all phones

activity_home_new.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_home_new"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home_new"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_new_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_bar_home_new.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ayush.prana.HomeNew">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_home_new" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_home_new.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.HomeActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageSlider"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/green"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="HOME"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:src="@drawable/menuicon" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.smarteist.autoimageslider.SliderView
        android:id="@+id/imageSlider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        app:sliderAnimationDuration="600"
        app:sliderAutoCycleDirection="back_and_forth"
        app:sliderAutoCycleEnabled="true"
        app:sliderCircularHandlerEnabled="true"
        app:sliderIndicatorAnimationDuration="600"
        app:sliderIndicatorGravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        app:sliderIndicatorMargin="15dp"
        app:sliderIndicatorOrientation="horizontal"
        app:sliderIndicatorPadding="3dp"
        app:sliderIndicatorRadius="2dp"
        app:sliderIndicatorSelectedColor="#5A5A5A"
        app:sliderIndicatorUnselectedColor="#FFF"
        app:sliderScrollTimeInSec="1"
        app:sliderStartAutoCycle="true">
    </com.smarteist.autoimageslider.SliderView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageSlider" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constitution"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="455dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageSlider">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Vata"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Pitha"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Kapha"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7" />
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:progressTint="@color/green"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView9"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView6"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:progress="50"/>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:progress="6"
            android:progressTint="@color/yellow"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/pgyello"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView10"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView7"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar3"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:progress="20"
            android:progressTint="@color/red"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/pgred"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView11"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView8"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:text="0"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:text="0"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView9" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:text="0"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:background="@color/green"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:background="@drawable/edgerounded"
                android:text="Update Your Answer"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/green"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView27"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#FFEB3B"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView12"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout2">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/food"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/foodbutton"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                />
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/yoga"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/yogabtn"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

app Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ayush.prana"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.3.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0' // v4
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation project(path: ':androidHorizontalListView')// v7
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.brucetoo.pickview:library:1.2.3'
    implementation project(path: ':photoview')
    implementation project(path: ':dialog')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

project Gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
ext {
    sdkVersion = 28
}
```

I can't find what is the problem for this random issue. for any positive reply thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your build.gradle too

Comment: yes Post your build.gradle!

Comment: app Gradle and project Gradle is included

Comment: do you get this error only in test cases?

Comment: as I can see the problem in your HomeView class. Is it your custom view class? If yes the problem is in inflating xml layout wich you use for this custom view class.

Comment: as I understand the purpose of  tools:context attribute there is not reason to write tools:context="com.ayush.prana.HomeNew" in any of the xml files you mentioned above. It just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

this line:

```
tools:context="com.ayush.prana.HomeNew"
```

should be used in: "activity_home_new.xml" not in "app_bar_home_new.xml"
so activity_home_new.xml should be like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
tools:context="com.ayush.prana.HomeNew">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_home_new"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home_new"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_new_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and remove `tools:context="com.ayush.prana.HomeNew"` from "app_bar_home_new.xml"

Comment: still same crash is occuring

Comment: @AyushpranaAyurvedic do you know the android version of the devices that crashes?

Comment: it is in redmi note 4 with android 7.0.. i checked with note 5 and note 7 it is working fine